# Url validation with preg_match

Tags: php, validation, url, preg-match

I want to make sure the link is from the chosen social type.
help!!

```
    $socialType = 'youtube';
    $link = 'https://www.youtube.co.uk/watch?v=DBK-Cy9ge4M';

    if (!preg_match("/^(http|https):\\/\\/[a-z0-9_]+$socialType*\\.[_a-z]{2,5}"."((:[0-9]{1,5})?\\/.*)?$/i",$link)) 
    {
         return Response::json('inValid'); 
    }
    {
         return Response::json('Valid');
    }
```

Comment: Youtube also has the `youtu.be` domain, and https://youtu.be/DBK-Cy9ge4M links to the same video you posted. You should also allow these videos (imho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be two options as- 
1. with preg_match -

```
$subject = "https://www.youtube.co.uk/watch?v=DBK-Cy9ge4M";
$pattern = '/^youtube/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,7), $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

2.  with strops as (Ruslan Osmanov)-

```
$socialType = 'youtube';
$link = 'https://www.youtube.co.uk/watch?v=DBK-Cy9ge4M';
if (strpos($link, $socialType) !== false) {
    return Response::json('Valid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check, if the link contains your substring using `strpos`:

```
$link = 'https://www.youtube.co.uk/watch?v=DBK-Cy9ge4M';
$type = 'youtube';

if (strpos($link, $type) !== false) {
  // passed
}
```

Or use a simple regular expression, if you want stricter check:

```
$reg_type = preg_quote($type, '/');

if (preg_match("/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?$reg_type/", $link)) {
  // passed
}
```

Note, you should escape values passed into the regular expression using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

The pattern should be just enough. Don't overcomplicate. It's generally impossible to write a perfect regular expression. For example, it is very unlikely to find HTTP(S) protocol prefix + optional "www." + "youtube." in an URL not belonging to Youtube.

Also, I wouldn't expect to get the answer with a universal regular expression for all kinds of social networks. Each has its own pattern.